# sqlite_exec for insert query is successful, but entry not found in sqlite table

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I'm facing a strange issue where in my insert query using sqlite_exec API says successful return value, but when I check in sqlite table I dont see that entry, Below is my code

Insert query : INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (0,1584633967816,1584634000,'dasdasda','1584634000','28641','dasdas','dsadas','dsadsa','/rewrwe','rwerewr','rewrewr','0',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

sqlite_exec code block:

sqliteError = sqlite3_exec(pSqlHandle, oSqlQuery.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL);

```
        if (sqliteError == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            LOG(DbgLogger, LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Query %s  successful\n",
                oSqlQuery.str().c_str());
            if (pSqlHandle) {
                sqliteError = sqlite3_close(pSqlHandle);
                if (sqliteError != SQLITE_OK) {
                    sqlRet = SQL_API_FAILURE;
                }
                else {
                    pSqlHandle = NULL;
                }
            }
            sqlRet = SQL_API_SUCCESS;
            if (m_useLockFile) {
                //write done, release write lock
                sqlRet = releaseWriteLock();
                /* reset write lock file name */
                bWriteLckAvailable = false;
            }
            break;
        }
```

I can see print "LOG(DbgLogger, LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Query %s  successful\n",)"

But when I do a select from command line on the  I dont see any entry as such

eg: select * from table_name where column_name=1584633967816;

Anyone faced similar issue ?

Comment: Are you failing to commit an open transaction before closing the database?

Comment: @Shawn Im actually not doing any BEGIN and COMMIT before transactions and after transactions

Comment: @Shawn  By default it should be in auto-commit mode right ?, Im using sqlite3

Comment: Also I have observed that sometime entries which actually got recorded to table are going missing when I connect to DB again and do a select * from <table_name>, This behavior is weird

Comment: Do you use full path when opening the database?